# How to change color of text when selected with Emotion library

Tags: css, reactjs, stylus, emotion

I am trying to convert a css code from Stylus to Emotion.
In Stylus as with CSS, you can add the pseudo element `::selection` to change the `color` when the text is selected.

```
// Stylus
#adventure
  max-width: 1400px
    ::selection
      color: $adventure-background
```

I tried this syntax but it does not seem to make it work

```
// Emotion
export const Adventure = styled.div`
  max-width: 1400px;
  /* @TODO not working */
  &::selection {
    color: ${colors.greenWater};
  }
`;
```

If someone has a clue! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure it will help, but this is how we do with `styled-component` ; have you tried without `&`, just `::selection` or `:selection` ?

Comment: This might be usefull : https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/666

Comment: Thank you @samb, I found this issue but it has not been really helpful. I tried different syntaxes like `&:selection` or `&::selection &` or without `&`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we finally found how to make css `::selection` work with Emotion. We converted our styled component to object and uses `& ::selection`. I did not tried with space and it was that!

```
// Emotion
export const Adventure = styled.div({
  maxWidth: '1400px',
  /* working now! */
  '& ::selection': {
    color: colors.greenWater,
  },
});
```